# JHipster with Okta Application Failed to Start due to UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: jhipster, okta, jhipster-gateway

Getting the following error when starting JHipster Gateway application after adding OKTA configuration:

```
$ cd saathratrigateway
$ ./mvnw

...
2020-11-13 22:31:16.278  WARN 80043 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationHeaderUtil' defined in file [/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/target/classes/com/saathratri/security/oauth2/AuthorizationHeaderUtil.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2020-11-13 22:31:16.280 DEBUG 80043 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.saathratri.domain.Authority      : Close successful.
2020-11-13 22:31:16.281 DEBUG 80043 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.saathratri.domain.User           : Close successful.
2020-11-13 22:31:16.281 DEBUG 80043 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.s.domain.User.authorities        : Close successful.
2020-11-13 22:31:16.282 DEBUG 80043 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Close successful.
2020-11-13 22:31:16.282 DEBUG 80043 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Close successful.
2020-11-13 22:31:16.479 ERROR 80043 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.saathratri.security.oauth2.AuthorizationHeaderUtil required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'authorizedClientService' in 'OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' in your configuration.
```

Any advise would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - figured it out. I had to create ~/.okta.env and then run source ~/.okta.env. See below....

```
$ vi ~/.okta.env

---
export SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI="https://dev-XXXXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default"
export SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET="XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER="https://dev-XXXXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default"
export OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_WEB="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_WEB="XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
---

$ source ~/.okta.env

$ cd saathratrigateway
$ ./mvnw
```

I was following instructions from https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/01/develop-microservices-jhipster-oauth.

Thank you Matt Raible!

Happy Diwali.

Comment: Sorry, it works without sudo. Have modified the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to see you figured it out! 